# Amer, amère, d'où vient la différence ?

Tags: adjectifs, orthographe, diacritiques

Est-ce que personne peut expliquer pourquoi qu'il n'y a aucun accent sur *amer*, mais pourtant dans sa forme féminine, on met un accent grave sur le **è** de *am**è**re*.

J'entends la différence entre *léger* et *légère*, mais *amer* et *amère* ont la même prononciation non ? Je n'entends aucune variation entre les deux.

Y a-t-il une règle qui explique ce genre de mots que je ne connais pas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La règle d'écriture est simple:

On ne met jamais d'accent sur le *e* de la terminaison *-er*, que le *r* final se prononce ou pas car dans ce dernier cas, l'accent ferait double emploi avec le *r* qui modifie la prononciation du *e* :

- *mer*
- *épicier*

Tous les mots français qui se terminent par *-ere* s'écrivent et se prononcent *-ère*.

- *mère*
- *épicière*

Il n'y a en revanche jamais d'accent écrit si la consonne est redoublée, bien que la prononciation soit la même que les mots en *-ère* :

- terre
- tonnerre

Il n'est donc pas possible de savoir à coup sûr comment prononcer les mots en *-er*, sachant quand même que :

- Tous les verbes en *-er* se prononcent [-e] (donc *chanter* comme *chanté*);
- La plupart des mots étrangers en *-er* se prononcent [-ɛʁ] (*carter, gangster, revolver, toner, hamster, laser*), parfois aussi [-œʁ] (dealer, hacker, leader, rocker, scooter, sniper) ;
- La plupart des mots français en *-er* se prononcent [-e].
  Quelques exceptions : *amer, cancer, cher, der, enfer, fer, 
  hiver, imper, mer, ver, éther*...

Comment: Quand vous dites "scooter" pensez-vous au véhicule ? Le cas échéant je l'aurais plutôt mis dans la colonne  [-ɛʁ], à moins qu'il y ait des variances de prononciation que je ne connaisse pas ? (Je parle le Français avec "l'accent breton")

Comment: @avazula Tous les mots que j'ai mis dans la liste "parfois [-œʁ]" peuvent avoir l'une ou l'autre prononciation suivant les locuteurs. cf. http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/scooter

Comment: J'avais loupé le "parfois". Merci pour le lien.

Comment: @avazula J'ai ajouté *aussi* pour être plus clair, c'est vrai que c'était ambigu.